# How to get values 1 or 0 from binary images

Tags: c#, emgucv

That is my code

```
Image<Gray, Byte> image = new Image<Gray, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
pictureBox1.Image = image.ToBitmap();
image1 = image1.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(50), new Gray(255));
```

I open an image from my desktop and convert it to grayscale and then binary.
I want to get either the values 1 or 0 from binary images in order to storage in matrix.
How can I do that?? I am using emgucv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Gray byCurrent = image1[x, y];
```

Or this :

```
Byte byCurrent = image1.Data[x, y, 0];
```

But you will have 0 or 255 values instead of 0 and 1.